# Google OAuth2 - Calendar API v3 - Java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I need some help, I have an application running on GAE and this read some information from a internet page and put inside my calendar as events.

And after google changed the API to v3, I can't connect using my own gmail.
Before that I was using CalendarService passing the credentials (email and app password).

Now I need to use another email created from OAuth2, but when I created an event, this event was created to "primary" calendar of this new email.

How can I connect using my own email and put these events inside the correct calendar and not the primary one?

Thanks for your help and time.
Celso

---

EDIT

I tried to read the calendar list but it's empty. I think that it's because the email that I use to connect using OAuth2, but I'm not sure about it.

Take a look, please.

Thx for your time.

`protected Calendar getCalendarService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {`

```
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId("xxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("cert.p12"))
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR))
        .build();

    return new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("appname").build();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more hours of search I found a possible solution that I describe as follow:

1. Share the calendar with write permission to service email (xxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com)
2. Ran my code and get the specific calendar id
3. Ran Calendar.events().insert("calendarid", event).execute()

I solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While inserting event, if you pass 'primary' in the Events: insert,

Event createdEvent = service.events().insert('primary', event).execute();

then event gets inserted into the primary calendar.

If you want to create event not to the primary one, then create secondary calendar. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert). You can get the calendar list from [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) where you can see the calendar ID of the primary and secondary calendars. Then when inserting the event, pass the secondary calendar ID instead of 'primary'in Events: insert. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I edited my question putting a piece of code that I use to connect to my gmail account. Could you take a look, please?